# Sending Bitmap file from Android to Matlab server

Tags: android, matlab, sockets, tcp, bitmap

I have a project which use an Android client to send image from its gallery to a Matlab server. At the moment, I am using socket connection to connect between the client and the server.

Here is the android client code

```
try {

    Socket socket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
    socket.setSoTimeout(3000);


    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    file.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
    int imageHeight = file.getHeight();
    int imageWidth = file.getWidth();
    byte array [] = stream.toByteArray();

    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);

    dos.writeInt(imageHeight);
    dos.flush();
    dos.writeInt(imageWidth);
    dos.flush();
    dos.write(array);
    dos.flush();

    dos.close();
    out.close();

    socket.close();
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The Image Width and Image Height are received by the server and it could be read without any problem. However, the bitmap file (byte array), is not readable at all. The result of the reading looks like as it is reading the byte directly instead of correctly converted it. Some of the result are :

> -2555936
>
> 1067590
>
> 1229324289.00000
>
> 16777217
>
> 65536
>
> -2424765
>
> 65793
>
> 16843009
>
> 16843009
>
> 16843009

etc.

Here is the Matlab code

```
tcpipServer = tcpip('0.0.0.0',7999,'NetworkRole','Server');
tcpipServer.Timeout = 10;
tcpipServer.InputBufferSize = 480*640*3*3;
fopen(tcpipServer);
imageSize = fread(tcpipServer, 2,'int32');

image = zeros(imageSize(1), imageSize(2), 3);
% for x=1:imageSize(1)
%   for y=1:imageSize(2)
    r = fread(tcpipServer, tcpipServer.BytesAvailable , 'int32');

%   end
% end

fclose(tcpipServer);
```

Anyone got any idea how to properly read the bytes and convert them to an image?

Thanks